# Fatal Error call to member function count() is non object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to query a database using pdo, but I cant figure out the problem. I have created an init file for my db details and server details and config file for configuration and index file and DB file.

**index.php**

```
<?php
  require_once 'core/init.php';

  $user =  Db::getInstance()->get('users',array('username', '=' , 'raja' ));

  if($user->count()) 
  {
      echo "No user";
  }
  else{
    echo "OK!";
  }


?>
```

**Db.php**

```
<?php
    class Db
    {
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo,
                $_query,
                $_error=false,
                $_results,
                $_count=0;
        private function __construct()
        {
            try
            {
                $this->_pdo =new PDO("mysql:host=" .Config::get('mysql/host') . ";dbname=" .Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                    die($e->getMessage());
            }

        }

        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if (!isset(self::$_instance)) 
            {
                self::$_instance = new Db();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }
        public function query($sql,$params=array())
        {
            $this->_error = false;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql))
            {   
                $x=1;
                if (count($params)) 
                {
                    foreach ($params as $param ) 
                    {
                        $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                        $x++;
                    }
                }
                if ($this->_query->execute())
                 {
                        $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                 }  
                 else 
                 {
                    $this->error=true;
                 }
            }
            return $this;               
        }
        public function action($action,$table,$where=array())
        {
            if(count($where) === 3)
            {
                $operators = array('=','<','>','>=','<=');

                $field     = $where[0];
                $operator  = $where[1];
                $value     = $where[2];

                if(in_array($operator,$operators))
                {
                    $sql = "{$action}FROM{$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                    if($this->query($sql,array($value))->error()){
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        public function get($table,$where)
        {
            return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
        }
        public function delete($table,$where)
        {
            return $this->action('DELETE ', $table,$where);
        }

        public function error()
        {
            return $this->_error;
        }
        public function count()
        {
            return $this->_count;
        }
    }
?>
```

It reports a fatal error about not finding the `count` object:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function count() on a non-object in
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\Student Management system\index.php on line 6

Comment: Did you include Db.php file in your  index.php ?

Comment: no m using the class as public so there is no need to include

Comment: Well how does your page reference the class if you don't include it? Public means you can use it on the page, but it doesn't just magically materialize unless you autoload it with `spl_autoload_register()`

Comment: the error message is clear enough, `$user` is a non object. debug $user and see if it is an object and it does in fact have the `count` method defined. I would say, right off the bat the query failed

Comment: @Rasclatt that class could have been included anywhere before the index.php file ex. core/init.php or something.

Comment: @SuryaJothika , hi this is NOT Java to auto include classes Without specifying its file.

Comment: if class is not included, you get a `Class not found` fatal error

Comment: **init.php:**'<?php
 session_start();

 $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
  'mysql' => array(
   'host' => '127.0.0.1',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'rajaraman',
   'db' => 'sms'
  ),
 'remember' => array(
  'cookie_name' => 'hash' ,
  'cookie_expiry' => 604800
  ),
  'session' =>  array(
   'session_name' => 'user' 
  )
  );
 spl_autoload_register(function($class){
  require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
 }); 
 require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
?>'

Comment: @AlexAndrei that is true, you would get  a fatal error.

Comment: @Rasclatt But i added  spl_auto_registered at init.php

Comment: @SuryaJothika don't focus on auto loading classes for now, simply do a var_dump after creating the `user` var to make sure you have the object. then make sure you have record in your database with username=raja

Comment: @Alex Andrei I cant get it ..where to use vardump?

Comment: Does your construct have to be private? This line that is breaking your class is: `$user =  Db::getInstance()->get('users',array('username', '=' , 'raja' ));` I could get your class to work if I made the `__construct()` public and made it `$user = new Db; $user_test =  Db::getInstance()->get('users',array('username', '=' , 'raja' )); `

Comment: If you are trying to make a singleton class, try making your `__construct()` public and make it return `$this` to a static variable like `if(!isset(self::$singleton)) self::$singleton = $this; return self::$singleton;` Something like that. Then you could do `$con = new Db();`, have a `protected function connect()` inside the `__construct` that contains your PDO connection. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Rasclatt has a good point

Comment: I will put it into an answer if not clear, but your `count()` will work that way.

Comment: i understand but little bit confusing

Comment: I will modify what you have in an answer and you can try it...

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare the object -- just calling an instance from part of the object class returns just that, a non-complete object part. You're calling the function as if it's just a function rather than if it is part of the class as a whole, so then referencing any other parts of the class as a whole the logic is lost because PHP only views it as a `get` function alone.

To solve:

```
<?php
  require_once 'core/init.php';
//here
$user = new Db();

$userSelect =  $user->get('users',array('username', '=' , 'raja' ));

...
```

From this, `$user` is your object.

## Sinlgeton

If you want to instead create the connection as a singleton, then each reference to a class method (~function) must be referenced with the singleton syntax - the reference to `count()` should therefore need to be rewritten into a Singleton syntax using `::` instead of `->` .

please read http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html